# shortestpathpointtolayer

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to use the shortestpathpointtolayer function in QGIS with Python as below.

```
start_points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('start points layer')[0]
end_points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('end points layer')[0]
network = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Network')[0]

# Looping through all start point features

for feat in start_points.getFeatures():
    start_point_id = feat["id"]
    start_point_geom = feat.geometry()

    parameters = {
        'DEFAULT_DIRECTION' : 2,
        'DEFAULT_SPEED' : 50,
        'DIRECTION_FIELD' : '',
        'END_POINTS' : end_points,
        'INPUT' : network,
        'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
        #'OUTPUT': 'memory:',
        'SPEED_FIELD' : '',
        'START_POINT' : start_point_geom,
        'STRATEGY' : 0,
        'TOLERANCE' : 0,
        'VALUE_BACKWARD' : '',
        'VALUE_BOTH' : '',
        'VALUE_FORWARD' : ''
        }
    
    result = processing.run("qgis:shortestpathpointtolayer", parameters)['OUTPUT']
    result.setName(f'Shortest path from point {start_point_id}') # changing the output name
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result) # adding output to the map
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 179, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 72, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Could not write feature into OUTPUT
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried executing the tool manually to make sure it is working with your data?